# Matlab :index exceeds matrix dimension

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

This is part of my matlab  code:

```
    indexPairs = matchFeatures(featuresA, featuresB, 'Metric', 'SSD');
    numMatchedPoints = cast(size(indexPairs, 2), 'int32');
    pointsA = pointsA(:, indexPairs(1, :));
    pointsB = pointsB(:, indexPairs(2, :));
```

**ERROR:**

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in all_three (line 81)
pointsA = pointsA(:, indexPairs(1, :));
```

Can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: What is `size(pointsA)` before line3? What is `max(indexPairs(1,:))`? What is `size(indexPairs)`?

Comment: @Dan right, sorry, edited. More coffee now.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite clear what causes the error. The maximum value of `indexPairs(1, :)` is a larger value than `size(pointsA,2)`. This throws an out of range error since `indexPairs` tries to access a value outside the matrix. This is probably caused by an indexing error in your code. To solve it you need to go to debug mode and find out where this happens in your code.

Answer (score 1):

From [matchfeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) documentation:

> indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1,features2) returns a P-by-2
>   matrix, indexPairs, containing P pairs of indices.

And `features1`, and `features2` are described like this:

> Features set, specified as an M1-by-N matrix, where N is the length of
>   each feature vector or a binaryFeatures object. This object for binary
>   descriptors is produced using the Fast Retina Keypoint (FREAK)
>   descriptor.

Try changing the last two lines from this:

```
pointsA = pointsA(:, indexPairs(1, :));
pointsB = pointsB(:, indexPairs(2, :));
```

... to this:

```
pointsA = pointsA(indexPairs(:, 1), :);
pointsB = pointsB(indexPairs(:, 2), :);
```

Also, `numMatchedPoints` calculation is incorrect, because `size(indexPairs, 2)` (number of columns) will always be 2. Change it to this (number of rows):

```
numMatchedPoints = cast(size(indexPairs, 1), 'int32');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you got `pointsA` and `pointsB` from one of the `detect****Features()` functions, correct?  Then `pointsA` and `pointsB` are one of the "point objects" such as `cornerPoints`.  Try using this:

```
 pointsA = pointsA(indexPairs(1, :));
 pointsB = pointsB(indexPairs(2, :));
```

Also, Rafael is correct:

```
numMatchedPoints = cast(size(indexPairs, 1), 'int32');
```